# Lacking libgdbm when installing perl

Tags: linux, perl, installation

I really want to know where does this libgdbm comes from and it seems it has been in

```
/usr/lib/libgdbm.so.2.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libgdbm.a
/usr/local/lib/libgdbm.la
/usr/local/lib/libgdbm.so
/usr/local/lib/libgdbm.so.3
/usr/local/lib/libgdbm.so.3.0.0
```

, but perl says

```
I used the command:

    cc -o try -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib try.c -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
     ./try

and I got the following output:

./try: error while loading shared libraries: libgdbm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The program compiled OK, but exited with status 127.
(The supplied flags or libraries might be incorrect.)

You have a problem.  Shall I abort Configure [y]  
Ok.  Stopping Configure.
```

so many files, I don't know why perl can't find any of them.

Comment: What OS/distribution are you using?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a package manager? They pull all the dependencies for you.

Comment: What OS are you on? Why are you compiling your own perl when you are just learning it? Most Unixes and Linux distros already ship with some ancient `perl`. The [`perlbrew` tool](http://perlbrew.pl/) can help with compiling a recent perl (just add `-Dusethreads` and be done with it).

Comment: Since I want to update perl to the latest version. And package manager didn't have a latest version

Comment: I am on scientific linux, BTW

Comment: @dspjm Of course the packages don't have the latest version. Seriously, give [`perlbrew`](http://perlbrew.pl/) a try, and install your perl 5.18.1 with that (It's what I do).

Comment: What's the output of `ldconfig -p | grep gdbm`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "-R/usr/local/lib" to LDFLAGS and/or CFLAGS environment variables.
If Linux perhaps change the order of searched directories in /etc/ld.so.conf